# Folder permissions to Nodejs Express + Apache with Proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, express, file-upload, chmod

I have a Linux Ubuntu with Apache serving files (PHP app) from "public/" folder. Inside this folder (public/node/), I have a nodejs express running via Apache ProxyPass/ProxyReverse. Everything works. But when I try to upload a file with the nodejs application (a simple/small API) and save to "public/node/fileupload", I got an error:

```
code: "EACCES"
errno: -13
```

This directory (and all others inside public/) has 775 permissions, and the user that started the nodejs application (my own user, not root) is at the same group as Apache (www-data).

If I change the public/node/fileupload directory permission to 777, the upload works and the owner of file is the user that started the nodejs express (my own user, as said above). But, you know, set a directory as chmod 777 is not a good choice.

Do you know how can I avoid the use of chmod 777 on "public/node/fileupload" to allow file upload to a configuration like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should change the owner of public/node/fileupload to www-data

Comment: Hello, @Emeeus! Sorry, forgot to say that all directories (public/ and it's children) have the owner and group as 'www-data'. Thank you anyway for your suggestion.